# Measure page load of angular app

Tags: angularjs, performance, pageload

Hi All I have tried the `var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd- window.performance.timing.navigationStart;` but value seems to be much smaller than actual time it takes to load the page.
Ideally I want to have a stopwatch that stop counting when the page is fully loaded. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the network tab in Chrome?  Or does it need to be programmatic to save in a log?

Comment: I guess the way to do would be to create a SetInterval that increments a int everytime its called until a loading condition is false

Comment: @TaylorAckley need to see it in the app.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I won't say that this method is not without its flaws, but if you are measuring the loading of data, here is one method you can use to achieve a loading counter.

1. Create a bool to evaluate against, isLoading.  Hoist it to `true`.
2. Create your int, `loadTime`.
3. Use a `SetInterval` to increment the int
4. Load some data
5. after you have processed the data, set the `isLoading` condition to `false`.

**Example:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/ARVpFd9NmlFNURlyS9SZ

```
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.isLoading = true;
        $scope.loadTime = 0;
        $scope.msg = '';

        var tmr = setInterval(function() {
          if(!$scope.isLoading || $scope.isLoading === false) {
            clearInterval(tmr);
          }
          $scope.loadTime += 0.01;
        }, 100);
        $http.get('https://unsplash.com')
          .then(function(res) {
            $scope.msg = 'Data is loaded';
            $scope.isLoading = false;
          });
```